# Configuring the repeat delay settings of a single keyboard key in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

I had a problem with unintentional double registered keys on my new laptop and I fixed it using the keyboard response configurations in the registry editor. However, I want the backspace to have less repeat delay than the other keys. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: wow this is disappointing... why can't they just add such an option? It doesn't seem to be too complicated

Comment: It would slow down keyboard processing by a large amount if every key had to be checked for its own repeat delay.

Comment: Although you can't configure only one keyboard key, a software solution can ignore backspace repetitions that arrive faster than a certain rate. Let me know if that interests you. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)